# ctag direct me to the generated file when using es6 babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, vim, ctags

I am using universal-ctags and i cannot make it to point to the original code but instead it is pointing to the generated code.

I generated the tags using the following command

```
ctags -R . --exclude=.webpack --exclude=node_modules
```

which .webpack is where the generated code located.

When I try to go to the definition, it will go to the generated code but not the original code.

I am new to vim and ctags and I did search a lot on Google but I couldn't find any answer.

Comment: "When I try to go to the definition" Where are you when you try that?

Comment: @romainl I was in my original code and I tried to go into a function but it then redirected me to the generated code of that function.